# Break and Pause key substitutes on HP Spectre x360 2-in-1 (2017)

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, hp-spectre

I'd like to be able to press a <kbd>Break</kbd> and/or <kbd>Pause</kbd> key on a **HP Spectre x360 2-in-1 (2017)** laptop. I'm running Windows 10. They keys aren't present on this laptop, so I'm trying to find a key combination to virtually press them.

I've tried, the following, seemingly without success:

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Are there any combinations that will work? Are there any applications that I can use to confirm that the virtual keypress is being recognised correctly?

Comment: Using Windows 10. Have updated main question

Comment: See this....https://appuals.com/what-is-the-alternative-to-pause-and-break-keys/

Comment: Find your specific model at this link, then look at the user manuals to see if they say if there are any ways to use pause/break on your pc....https://support.hp.com/us-en/products/identify?q=HP%20Spectre%20x360&filter=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, duh. `Pause` is printed right there on the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key:

So, in order to send the `Break/Pause` key, you need:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I also have HP Pavilion x360 convertible.

Another option is to do fn + right shift.